# how to call href in Link Button in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How to call href tag in Link Button

Suppose

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkViewAll" CssClass="button" runat="server" >
                                        <span>View All</span>
                                      </asp:LinkButton>
```

then How to Call The follow href in

```
 <a href="#dialog" name="modal">Simple Window Modal</a>
```

in Link Button onClientClick

Comment: Are you after a client side click rather than server-side..?

Comment: @dinesh-sharma do you want to set `href` property on `LinkButton`

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is execute some client side code, then you do not need a server control at all. Just use an `<a>...</a>`

If however you want to use the LinkButton you can use the [`OnClientClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclientclick%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property to execute client side script.

Comment: but i also need server side  click event also.

Comment: You need to detail the order of events for us here. There is no magic in server side and client side events. They don't happen simultaneously as any server side event requires a complete postback. So either you execute a script on the client, wait for user feedback, and then postback. ***OR*** you postback, and then register a script to execute immediately after the page is rendered. Which one is it?